# Google Play не пропускает игру после добавления Firebase в Unity

Tags: unity3d-android, admob, firebase-android

Всем привет! Ситуация следующая. Импортировал в игру на Unity, admob. Загрузил игру в Google play, все прошло успешно. Через пару дней, решил добавить в игру Firebase, для аналитики но, при отправке на модерацию, Google Play не пропустил игру с ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала не понял, почему игру не пропустили но, потом решил удалить Firebase из игры и загрузить игру еще раз в Google Play и игра опять прошла успешно модерацию. Как настроить Firebase?